# How is the default auto-switching wallpaper in Unity made? (15.10)

Tags: unity, desktop-background

You all know, when you go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Appearance</kbd> and look at the available background images, this looks like the screenshot below:

[image: default backgrounds in 15.10]

The third background icon has a clock symbol on it and selecting it will cause the wallpaper to change every *[?]* minutes and cycle through all of the default backgrounds.

**Now my question is how this is made.** I know there are several external programs to auto-switch wallpapers and even writing a script for it is not hard. But I am interested in how this specific Unity feature is done and how this automatic wallpaper-switcher can be customized e.g. with other images or different delay times.

---

Hint:

I've found the file `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/wily.xml` which seems to be involved in that wallpaper changing magic somehow. But still I don't know how exactly this works, if it can handle more files, how the syntax is and what stuff it supports, etc.

Here's a dump of its contents:

```
<background>
  <starttime>
    <year>2009</year>
    <month>08</month>
    <day>04</day>
    <hour>00</hour>
    <minute>00</minute>
    <second>00</second>
  </starttime>
<!-- This animation will start at midnight. -->
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tramonto_a_Scalea_by_Renatvs88.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tramonto_a_Scalea_by_Renatvs88.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Light_my_fire_evening_sun_by_Dariusz_Duma.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Light_my_fire_evening_sun_by_Dariusz_Duma.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Light_my_fire_evening_sun_by_Dariusz_Duma.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Sitting_Here,_Making_Fun_by_Philipp_Haegi.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Sitting_Here,_Making_Fun_by_Philipp_Haegi.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Sitting_Here,_Making_Fun_by_Philipp_Haegi.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Moss_inflorescence_by_carmelo75.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Moss_inflorescence_by_carmelo75.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Moss_inflorescence_by_carmelo75.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Breaker_by_Lyle_Nel.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Breaker_by_Lyle_Nel.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Breaker_by_Lyle_Nel.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_by_dariuskws.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_by_dariuskws.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Blue_by_dariuskws.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Hotel_by_sarcasmrules2011.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Hotel_by_sarcasmrules2011.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Hotel_by_sarcasmrules2011.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Mediterranean_Sea_by_simosx.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Mediterranean_Sea_by_simosx.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Mediterranean_Sea_by_simosx.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Abstract_Ubuntu_by_Marek_Koteluk.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Abstract_Ubuntu_by_Marek_Koteluk.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Abstract_Ubuntu_by_Marek_Koteluk.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tramonto_a_Scalea_by_Renatvs88.jpg</to>
  </transition>
</background>
```

Comment: Try duplicating a block (copy-pasta) of <static> and <transition>, but change the file location in between the <to> tags. You'll see.